# How to get return error code of popen?

Tags: process, kill

I want the error code which return by 'popen'.

Popen command is as below:

```
fp = popen("/system/bin/pgrep -f  "/system/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -re -i /data/misc/qmmf/LiveStreaming_FIFO_1.264 -codec copy -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://11.11.11.11:554/live/stream1?wowzatoken=B-VDkZmspHh-G49SQIKghznGAHryq5zNc3NE7KEDgx8=" ","r");
```

I am getting the PID of the currently running ffmpeg process and am reading this popen() using a file pointer in an array. Then, read the PID(char by chat and using atoi()) and kill that PID.

Checking the `(fp == NULL)`, but not getting NULL pointer.

Mainly, I want to kill that ffmpeg process. Not all running ffmpeg process, but the specific one which distinguishes by its name.

Are there any other ways apart from this?

Any suggestions would helpful.

Comment: Is this C? On Linux system?

Comment: Your example also has double quotes within the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a Linux system, [`man 3 popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) explains the programming interface. `popen()` will return  NULL when fork/pipe call fail or memory cannot be allocated. On success *I/O stream pointer* is returned. The value of the variable doesn't change unless a new value is assigned to the variable.

To wait for the process to terminate, you should use `pclose()`, which will return -1 on error. Additionally, both functions set [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) if an error occurs.

If you need to reliably get the child process' PID, you need to do `fork()` call in your code and use it's return value. Since you won't be using `popen()`, you also need to set up pipe(s) in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I fully understand your question, but this is what the man page says about `popen()` errors:

> RETURN VALUE
>   The popen() function returns NULL if the fork(2) or pipe(2) call fails, or if it cannot allocate memory.
>  
>   ERRORS
>   The popen() function does not set errno if memory allocation fails.  If the underlying fork(2) or pipe(2) fails, errno is set appropriately. If the type argument is invalid, and this condition is detected, errno is set to EINVAL.

Are you checking `errno` in addition to checking the return value?